# Kohana orm - get child and grand-child object

Tags: php, orm, kohana

I have a problem in Kohana ORM in loading object children.
My database tables looks that:

```
-objects (something like "houses", but objects sounds better in my opinion)
  -id
  -name
  -title
  -author
  -city (id link to cities.city_id)
  -description
  -access
-cities
  -city_id
  -country (id link to countries.country_name)
  -city_name
-countries
  -country_id
  -country_name
```

and my models:

```
class Model_Object extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'objects';
    protected $_table_columns = array(
        'id' => NULL,'name' => NULL,
        'title' => NULL,
        'author' => NULL,
        'city' => NULL,
        'description' => NULL,
        'access' => NULL,
        'created' => NULL
    );
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_has_one = array(
        'city'=>array(),
        'author'=>array(
            'model'=>'User',
            'foreign_key'=>'user_id',
        )
    );
}

class Model_City extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'cities';
    protected $_table_columns = array('city_id'=>NULL,'city_name'=>NULL);
    protected $_primary_key = 'city_id';
    protected $_has_one = array('country'=>array(
        'model'=>'country',
        'foreign_key'=>'country',
    ));
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'objects'=>array(),
    );
}

class Model_Country extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'countries';
    protected $_table_columns = array(
        'country_id'=>NULL,
        'country_name'=>NULL,
    );
    protected $_primary_key = 'country_id';
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'cities'=>array(
            'model'       => 'city',
            'foreign_key' => 'country'
        ),
    );
}
```

I need to get object's object including name of country and city. I found this:

```
ORM::factory('Object')->with('City')->with('City:Country')->find_all();
```

[here](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm/advanced#optimizing_one-to-one_relationships_using_with) but it returns cities ids instead of cities objects.
So my question is: How to get object's objects with child objects in my presented tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the query that is being executed this way:

```
echo View::factory('profiler/stats');
```

I believe the main problem is your relations. The find_all objects with cities and cities:countries looks fine.

What you might want to consider is following Kohana ORM naming convention. So the tables would be objects, cities and countries, they would all have id as their primary key. Objects table would have a city_id column (refering to id in cities table) and cities would have country_id which would "point" to id column in countries table. If you keep the names of tables, columns and models right you won't even need to define table names or foreign keys in your models separately.

Now since every object has a city assigned to it and every city might have zero to n objects you want to declare in Object model that it BELONGS TO city. And in city model use HAS MANY objects.

Also city BELONGS TO country and country HAS MANY cities.

Now you should be able to get data as following:

```
$objects = ORM::factory('Object')->with('City')->with('City:Country')->find_all();

$objects = $cityObject->objects->find_all();

$cities = $countryObject->cities->find_all();
```

etc.

More about relationships can be found [here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/relationships)